# How to generate an array of unique UUID values using R?

Tags: r, uuid

I want to create a dataframe full of UUID values. Obviously, each UUID in the dataframe should be unique. Furthermore, my end use requires that each UUID value be enclosed in braces (e.g.: {e681b500-dafb-11e9-9912-1319dd65aab1}).

I am using the package [uuid](http://www.rforge.net/uuid/). Unfortunately, I've found that in some scenarios, the command [UUIDgenerate()](https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/uuid/UUIDgenerate.html) does not generate unique UUID values.

The code below initializes a data frame of desired size, then uses a for loop to call UUIDgenerate() for each index in the dataframe. I've called the command within the paste() command to enclose each UUID value in braces.

```r
library('uuid')

NoOfRows = 5
NoOfCols = 150
df_UUIDs = data.frame(matrix(ncol=NoOfCols,nrow=NoOfRows))

for (i in c(1:NoOfRows)){
    for (j in c(1:NoOfCols)){
        df_UUIDs[i,j] = paste("{",UUIDgenerate(FALSE),"}",sep="")
    }
}
```

The code above does successfully generate a dataframe full of UUIDs enclosed in braces, but the values are not all unique!

To show this, the code below counts the number of entries in the dataframe, then counts the number unique values in the dataframe. The test reveals that the code above generates only between 2-38 unique UUIDs when there should be 750.

```r
library('dplyr')
dim(as.data.frame(unlist(df_UUIDs)))[1]
dim(distinct(as.data.frame(unlist(df_UUIDs))))[1]
```

Here are some additional clues:

1. The number of unique values generated is different every time I run the code
2. The error does not occur when argument use.time=TRUE
3. The error does not occur when the paste() command is omitted
4. Although this error occurs on my machine (R 3.6.1, Windows, x86-64) it does not occur when tested elsewhere such as [rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/) (R 3.4.4, linux-gnu, x86_64).

Have others encountered similar problems with UUIDgenerate()? Does anyone have an idea for why the error would occur?

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue -- `R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) / Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)` only generated 29 unique UUID's. `R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26) / Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)` succeeded in generating 750 as expected. You could try filing a bug report here, but I'm not sure whether you'll get a response.

Comment: Why use `UUIDgenerate(use.time = FALSE)`? Hashing the system time is a good way to add additional entropy to your UUIDs (as evidenced by that fixing your problem in #2)

Comment: In terms of code review, your entire code could be rewritten in a single line: `result = as.data.frame(matrix(replicate(ncol * nrow, sprintf('{%s}', uuid::UUIDgenerate())), nrow = nrow), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` — It might make sense to split up this line for readability but honestly not very much.

Comment: @Brian That is certainly a fair recommendation, but Jonathan appears to have uncovered a platform specific bug that essentially hamstrings the entire `uuid` package on some platforms, that seems notable enough to be addressed.

Comment: There are some additional reports and notes here: https://github.com/s-u/uuid/issues/2

Comment: Also I cannot reproduce your fix in #3, eliminating `paste`. That still produces dupes for me.

Comment: An alternative library is https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ulid, which uses a different C implementation.

Comment: @Brian - Regarding the question of whether or not to use system time. I found that `UUIDgenerate(use.time = TRUE)` generates very little diversity among the values generated. The values generated are reliably distinct, but only differ from one another by a few characters. Whether or not this matters probably depends on the application.